# Php Error: include_once(): Failed opening 'XXXXXXX' for inclusion (include_path='XXXXX') in XXXXX on line 7

Tags: php

I am here because my php code keeps giving me this annoying error whenever i include something from a directory , or just including something from a file. The error is originating from includes.php. I later found that you have to add the COMPLETE path to the directory. So I did, but it just keeps giving me the same error.

My code:

```
include_once (__DIR__."/inc/defines.inc.php");
```

Comment: Btw stack exchange Switched my __Dir__ with Dir for some reason

Comment: I edited it just now; weird though. Use indentation instead and not `<code></code>` @FumerianGaming

Comment: have you tried with giving absolute path? if yes, can you check the file permissions

Comment: @FumerianGaming that's how the formatting works here. you should read up on it. also: can you show the value of `__DIR__`? and make absolutely sure the requested file exists?

Comment: Usually, on include/require errors, you usually get an another error justbefore a one like this telling the problem. Could you show us them?

Comment: Remember `__DIR__` returns the full path to the file in which the `__DIR__` command is located in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: <code>__DIR__</code> = /var/www/html/ and the file im trying to include  is located in /var/www/html/test/inc/sql_lib.inc.php

Comment: I have also changed the file permissions to everyone but it still doesnt work

Comment: My question has gone unanswered.

Comment: It is not a duplicate of anything. I have tried everything even from the suppose "duplicate," but nothing worked.

Comment: btw I have got banned from asking questions

Answer (score 1):

Note that `__DIR__` gets replaced by the files own directory path. The issue here is most likely that the path from the script you include does not match the directory you want to include a file from.

A common practice is to have a file at the root of your project that defines the root path. If you include that config file (or whatever you call it), it is easier for you to include other files.

For example. imagine a project like this:

- config.php
- foo/bar.php
- foo/baz/bat.php

Example content of `config.php`:

```
<?php
define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__);
```

Now, the content of `foo/baz/bat.php` could be:

```
<?php
// Get the config file
include '../../config.php';

// Include the content of foo/bar.php
include ROOT_PATH . '/foo/bar.php';
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but it still gave me the same error.